# What's the best way to get the number of matching elements from two lists - provided there are repetitions in both lists?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have 2 lists with repeating elements in both. I need the total number of common items in both the lists.

eg: `arr1=[5,5,4,4,3]` and `arr2=[4,5,3,4,5]`

So I want an output of '5' since all 5 elements of both lists are common

The `set` intersection concept does not work because the intersection contains 3 elements `(3,4,5)` - since these are the unique, common elements in both. This is **not** what I want.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array(arr1)
b = np.array(arr2)
c=np.intersect1d(a,b)
```

Comment: Do you actually have lists or arrays? If you are working with `list` objects, there are probably better ways of doing this than working with `numpy`.

Comment: I think the solution for lists might just work as well. Do share if you've got something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not use numpy, but you can create Counters for each list and sum the minimum count of the intersection.

```
from collections import Counter

def count_intersection(arr1, arr2):
    c1 = Counter(arr1)
    c2 = Counter(arr2)
    common = set(c1).intersection(set(c2))
    result = sum(min(c1[n], c2[n]) for n in common)
    return result
```

Test cases:

```
count_intersection([5,5,4,4,3], [4,5,3,4,5])
5

count_intersection([5,5,4,4,3], [5,4,4,4,3])
4

count_intersection([1,1,1,1,1], [1,2,2,2,2])
1

count_intersection([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4])
4
```

This runs in O(n), and it handles the multiplicity correctly for both in the first and second test cases, and does not modify the original array. One drawback is that it creates two Counter objects with size k, the number of unique elements in the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `numpy.isin` on the intersection, so something to the effect of:

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = [5,5,4,4,3]
arr2 = [4,5,3,4,5]
a = np.array(arr1)
b = np.array(arr2)
c = np.intersect1d(a,b)

print(min(np.isin(a,c).shape, np.isin(b, c).shape))
```

Not sure whether you need the `min` or `max`, but I think you can tailor the above to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Following will give you the list of all matching elements between two arrays `arr1` and `arr2`:

```
matches = []

for x in arr1:
    if x in arr2:
        matches.append(x)
        arr2.remove(x)

print(matches)
```

One thing to mention here is that `arr2` will have all the common elements removed after this code runs, so it's worth to replace it with its copy in case you need the original array.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution using pointers

```
arr1.sort()
arr2.sort()
arra1_len = len(arr1)
arra2_len = len(arr2)

common_elements = []

pointer_a1 = 0
pointer_a2 = 0

while(pointer_a1 < arra1_len and pointer_a2 < arra2_len):
    if arr1[pointer_a1] > arr2[pointer_a2]:
        pointer_a2 += 1
    elif arr1[pointer_a1] < arr2[pointer_a2]:
        pointer_a1 += 1
    else:
        common_elements.append(arr1[pointer_a1])
        pointer_a1 += 1
        pointer_a2 += 1

print(len(common_elements))
```

Sort the lists and increment the individual pointers after comparing the elements at the pointer location.